# Should I be using a validation curve accuracy score in lieu of error bars for a model fit to time series data?

Tags: error-propagation

Normally when doing a fit to some time series data (e.g., a polynomial fit), functions will return an associated error with each fitted point. I'm now trying out `scikit-learn`'s [support vector regression (SVR)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) fitting instead, which doesn't have any such return. There is a handy function in `scikit-learn` called `validation_score` that can tell me the accuracy score of various fits, from which I select the best one. So maybe that's good enough? But as a scientist, I'm wondering if this will get slapped down in peer review of a publication.

What's the right way to propagate the errors of my time series data through the SVR fit?

Comment: I don't think you'll find the answer here. Maybe try [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions) community instead?

Comment: I'll try there as well... it's kind of weird one that spans programming, science, and math.